# Dynamic text and dropdown value in taipy

Tags: python, dynamic, dropdown, taipy

i am using the below folder structure for my project
[folder structure for pages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2yVe.png)

in overview.md i have a text where its mentioned "total number of projects:"
similarly i have a create project and a dropdown selectorthat list all avaiable projects in create.md, now the problem is when ever i am creating a project the dropdown values are not updating and also in the overview_md "total number of projects:" stays the same.

home.py

```
from taipy.gui import Gui
import taipy as tp


from user_interface.taipy.pages.create.create import create_md
from user_interface.taipy.pages.overview.overview import overview_md
from user_interface.taipy.pages.upload.upload import upload_md
from user_interface.taipy.pages.root import root



pages = {
    '/':root,
    "Overview":overview_md,
    "create":create_md,
    "Upload":upload_md,

}

gui_multi_pages = Gui(pages=pages)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tp.Core().run()
    
    gui_multi_pages.run(title="Dataforge",dark_mode=False)
```

overview.md

```
## Quick overview 

Total projects  : <|{total_projects}|>
```

overview.py

```
def get_no_collections():
    error,collections = shepard_client.get_all_collections()
    print("checked total_projects")
    if collections is not None:
        for collection in collections:
            #print(f"ID: {collection.id}, Name: {collection.name}")
            collections_list.append((collection.id, collection.name))
        return len(collections_list)
    else:
        print("Failed to fetch collections.")
        return "Error getting collections"
    
total_projects= get_no_collections()
```

```
create.md
`<|{selected_projects}|selector|lov={available_projects}|type=Collection|adapter={lambda c: (str(c.id), c.name)}|label=Select Project|on_change=update_plist|dropdown|>
```

create.py

```
class Collection:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
error,collection = shepard_client.get_all_collections()
available_projects = [Collection(data.id, data.name) for data in collection]
```

how can i change the variable value every time i switch pages or refresh page elements so that its updated?

i tried updating using state. when there is create button clicked but doesnt really update the dropdown list.

```
def update_plist(state) -> None:
    """
    Function to update the list of available projects.
    """
    try:
        error, u_collections = shepard_client.get_all_collections()
        if not error:
            # Update the state with the new list of collections
            state.available_projects = [Collection(data['id'], data['name']) for data in u_collections]
        else:
            print("Error fetching collections:", error)
    except Exception as e:
        print("Exception in update_plist:", e)
```

Comment: Can you replicate the issue with minimal code? You should be able to do this automatically directly. However, to answer your question, you can use the [`on_navigate`](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/gui/callbacks/#navigation-callback) callback. Each time, you refresh your page or navigate to a page, this callback will be called in Taipy. Define it in your `home.py` and inside it use `state.refresh('name_of_variable')`.

Comment: def on_navigate(state,, page_name):
    state.refresh('name_of_your_db')
    return page_name

Comment: but in my case, the variable is declared overview.py another page not in home.py.
hence I am getting error: TaipyGuiWarning: Variable 'total_projects' is not available in either the '__main__' or '__main__' modules.

Comment: You can access variables with `state['overview'].name_of_variable`. [Taipy Doc](https://docs.taipy.io/en/latest/manuals/gui/binding/#page-scope-in-callbacks)